# How to determine wether a graph (directed or undirected) contains a cycle in O(|V|) time.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In an old practice exam of my University they ask the following:

"Give an algorithm that takes as input a graph $G = (V, E)$, stored in an adjacency list, and that returns True is there exists at least one cycle in $G$ and False otherwise. Your algorithm should run in $O(|V|)$ time."

I asked my professor and he replied that it should work for both directed and undirected graphs. Now, what I have tried is the following:
By running depth-first-search and make it return when the first cycle is found, it indeed can determine wether $G$ has a cycle yes or no. Moreover, in all my examples it did so in $O(|V|)$ time since it never had to do more than |V| operations. The hard part however, is to show that it always will only take $O(|V|)$ time.

My question: how can I show that this algorithm will always run in $O(|V|)$ time? Also, if my approach is wrong I would very much appreciate a push in the right direction.

I have found the answer to this question and would like to submit an answer, how do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: For undirected graphs: If the number of edges is at least as large as the number of vertices, then the graph contains a cycle.

Comment: I have found an answer to my own question. This answer is different from the similar question someone had suggested. How can I answer my own question?

Comment: Does your answer also answer the other question? Then you can answer there.